# Multiple profiles in Chrome: Syncing between macs? + Safari? + Alternative?

Tags: google-chrome, safari, workflow, profiles

I work with multiple ppl, and have each person set up with their own profile in my Chrome browser.

In short they all have diffrent (etc. social)-profiles on all kind of diffrent websites that i have to manage, lets say facebook, google+ and so on.

It kind of works okay, but not sure if this can be done in another / smother way?

As of such I have 3 questions:

1) Is it possible to migrate to safari and do something similar? It seams safari does not use profiles.

2) What is the easist way to sync over several Macs? ... like right now i have to manually create the chrome profile on all of the Macs, then log into each account manually. This is time consuming when I have 50 accounts and sync them over 3 macs. Esp when chrome had to be reinstalled once in a while or stuff like that.

3) Is there a smarter way to do something like this?

thnx